# How to evaluate a statistical model with given (=not optimised) coefficients?

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I have a very simple statistical model y = a * b.

I know all the variables (a, b, and y) and I do not want to add any optimized coefficients (the intercept should be 0 and the coefficients on a and b are effectively 1).

What I need is the explained variance (R2), but I cannot figure out a simple way to tease it out without calculating all the formulas from scratch. Is there anything similar to *statsmodel OLS rsquared* but for a model with fixed coefficients?

I mainly use python but happy to use R if it is easier.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be really helpful if you code post some of your code on what all have you tried and where are you stuck. This will enable the community help you in a better manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scikit-learn's `r2_score` method, which you can find [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html). All you have to do is actually to compute your predicted dependent variable `y` using your coefficients and your data.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

# here's the truth value of y
y_true = [3, -0.5, 2, 7]

# here's your single featue x
x = [1, 2.3, 3.1, 0.9]

# and here's your coefficient b and your intercept a
i = [0, 0, 0, 0]
b = 0.3

# compute the predicted value of y using your coefficients
y_pred = [n+m for (n, m) in zip(i, [j*b for j in x])]

# display the R2 score using scikit-learn's r2_score method
print(r2_score(y_true, y_pred))
```

On a side note, computing the R2 from scratch would not be much more complex than this...